# Twitter share - hashtag doesnt show up

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have been creating custom twitter button, everything works fine except for hashtag. The Generated url is 
[https://twitter.com/share?text=Live%20the%20life%20you%20love%20and%20love%…20you%20live.-Bob%20Marley&hastags=quotes,thought&url=http://goo.gl/TaEpJm](https://twitter.com/share?text=Live%20the%20life%20you%20love%20and%20love%25%E2%80%A620you%20live.-Bob%20Marley&hastags=quotes,thought&url=http://goo.gl/TaEpJm)

Answer (score -1):

It is not `hastag`, it is `hashtag`. So use `hashtag` instead of `hastag`